# Clean mold from a lemon squeezer

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

I've used this `lemon squeezer` but forgot to clean it.
Now that I need it again I can't clean the mold in it (please see the picture), because it's too narrow.

[image: Mold inside a lemon squeezer]

Is there a practical way to clean it?

Comment: Detail: Note that the photograph depicts a hand operated citrus "juicer" or "reamer".

Comment: The contaminated nooks and crannies of this item makes thorough cleaning of it difficult or impossible. It's a candidate for a landfill at this point. Don't compromise your health to save an inexpensive item.

Comment: @Stan I put it in the dishwater few days ago as Brett suggested. It's cleaner than it used to be on the picture and usable again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lemon squeezer is dishwasher safe, the spraying jets and hot water of the dishwasher may be able to kill and blast off all the mold.  Just make sure to secure the lemon squeezer so it doesn't fly off the rack in the dishwasher and bang around; it might wind up in a place where water isn't spraying, and it won't get cleaned.

Comment: I'm not sure if its dishwasher safe (It's made of plastic). All I know is that some mold persists when I've drowned in soapy water and used cotton buds to clean it.

Answer (score 2):

Put it into hot water for some time (an hour or two), then try to wash it using something narrow enough e.g. cotton buds (as @TiO mentioned) or bottle brush like [this one](https://groceries.morrisons.com/productImages/326/326974011_0_640x640.jpg?identifier=8ec5709c11299eddfe9605e65fd88272) or even better [this one](https://www.saison.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/r/e/redecker-brush-conical.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You could bathe the lemon squeezer in a bath of bleach & water for a little bit of time then clean the mold off using cotton buds.

If you don't like to use bleach, you could always try just with soapy water & cotton buds to clean them.

Comment: -1 No. Bleach (or a biocide) is NOT recommended for removing mould infestations. According to Wikipedia, killing mould in this manner is insufficient since chemicals and proteins causing reactions in humans remain in dead mould. Hot soapy water, thorough direct-contact scouring, rinse and rapid drying is recommended for non-porous materials. If this cannot be done, dispose of the contaminated item in construction waste.

Answer (score 1):

Those kettle-sized steam cleaners are pretty handy for jobs like this.